# How to make auto sizing container in android studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIN8d.png)

here is the link to the image.
There is a container that stores photos, and it can automatically expand and reduce depending on the number of photos.
How to implement such a container in android.
Maybe there is some kind of built-in View?

Comment: I guess that's exactly what `wrap_content` does